# My facebook like box not showing in any of my browsers

Tags: html, facebook, google-chrome

I'm using Dreamweaver CC to test my Facebook Like Box in Chrome, FireFox, Opera and Safari. However, it doesn't appear. I'll get a grey box in Chrome, which is the facebook like box but it says "The file or directory could not be found".

```
 <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FTJs-Catfish-Wings%2F162057770483683&amp;width&amp;height=590&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=true&amp;stream=true&amp;show_border=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; height: 485px; width: 345px; padding-top: 8px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "http:" or "https:" to the src attribute. "//" is the recommended way (because it takes the protocol from the website), but it will only work on a webserver. If that does not work, upload your code to a webserver or start a local one and work with localhost.